# Linq stored procedure to return XML

Tags: c#, xml, entity-framework, linq, stored-procedures

I am using Entity Framework code-first approach. I want to call a stored procedure from the `DbContext` class and to get XML output.

Stored procedure (SQL Server):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE xml_test    
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @xml1 xml

    SET @xml1 = (SELECT * from Product FOR XML RAW) 

    SELECT @xml1 AS my_xml
END
```

LINQ Entity Framework:

```
using (DBContext db = new DBContext())
{
    var ProductList = await db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("exec xml_test");
}
```

Here the `ProductList` list is returning -1.

I want to get the xml output which is returned by the stored procedure.

Note: I have also tried methods like: **ExecuteSqlCommand, SqlQuery** with no help.

Comment: I guess [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339750/entity-framework-stored-procedure-return-value) might help.

Answer (score 5):

I think you can use `SQLQuery` like this:

```
using (var dbcontext = new DBContext())
{
    //Reading stored procedure results as List<string>
    var r = dbcontext.Database.SqlQuery<string>("EXEC xml_test").ToList(); //Note: EXEC is optional

    //Joining strings to one string that causes in resulting long strings
    var xmlString = string.Join("", r);

    //Now you can load your string to a XmlDocument
    var xml = new XmlDocument();

    //Note: You need to add a root element to your result
    xml.LoadXml($"<root>{xmlString}</root>");
}
```

> Note: To get records from your stored procedure you need to add `SET NOCOUNT ON;` after `BEGIN` ;).

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[xml_test] 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT * from dbo.AspNetUsers FOR XML RAW;
END
```

Comment: Shouldn't need the `EXEC` part of the statement - just `xml_test`.

Comment: @TiesonT. tnx, I add a note about that ;).

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by shA.t "[FOR XML](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx)" can be used. However one thing to take care of while using is the truncation of string/XML (returned after function call via EF) at around 2k characters, to handle this scenario you can have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228303/entity-framework-calling-a-for-xml-stored-procedure-truncates-at-2033-characters). Also if the code design allows, you can even use [Ouptput parameters with Enitity Framework](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8190877c-4dc0-4968-b2ed-1c892eb3b687/execute-sp-which-has-xml-datatype-output-parameter-in-entity-framework?forum=adodotnetentityframework).

Answer (score 2):

`Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` executes commands used for CRUD operation, not querying.

Using `Database.SqlQuery` is for queries. It will return elements of a given type but `xml` isn't a primitive type and probably it's a reason why LINQ not working. Try `cast` xml in stored procedure to `nvarchar(max)` this will be string type.

. So your stored procedure should look like:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE xml_test    
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @xml1 xml

    SET @xml1 = (SELECT * from Product FOR XML RAW) 

    SELECT CAST(@xml1 as nvarchar(max))
END
```

Comment: sorry, unable to cast.